# SASS live compiler Mixing / Variables not updating until I update main scss file

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass

I am new to SASS so please forgive me on my terminology and understanding. I am going through some tutorials on youtube and it has been great, the video is called 'Learn Sass In 20 Minutes | Sass Crash Course'. I am using visual studio code and what is tripping me up is the part where he has me create a _header.scss file along with _variables.scss as extensions of the main style.scss. Where the header from the style.scss is an @import 'header'; from the _header.scss using a @mixin variable.

I am running the live server on visual studio code and it will not update until I manually save all the files that I changed then also save the 'style.scss' in the end. Is there a way I could say modify the _header.scss file and _variables.scss and have it auto-update the style.scss?

If that doesn't make sense I will say it this way. I have a mixin variable and other '$variable's in my main style.scss file. When I make changes to the _variable.scss file and the _header.scss, is there a way I can just save these and have it automatically update the style.scss file as well? It is extremely time consuming having to go through and save them all to get it to do one update.

I tried making a key in VS code for 'Save All' multiple ways from online tutorial. Nothing works. I hope I am making sense, it is hard for me to explain being new to this. Thank you

```
style.scss

@import 'variables';
@import 'header';



.contact {
  @include flexCenter(row, grey);
}

_header.scss

@mixin flexCenter($direction, $background) {
  height: 25vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: $direction;
  background: $background;
}

header {

  @include flexCenter(row, rgb(31, 28, 28));
  color: $textColor;

  h1 {
    color: $textColor;
  }

  button {
    background: $primaryBtn;

    &::after {
      content: "o";
    }
  }
}

_variables.scss

$textColor: brown;
$primaryBtn: pink;
```

Comment: Do you mean "update the style.CSS" and not SCSS? There's no reason for an update to a partial (the underscored files, e.g. `_variables.scss`) to update the style.SCSS file. What should happen, is your compiled CSS file *should* get updated when you make a change to a partial.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right in saying it like that. When I update the partials and press save nothing changes. Then I have to go over to the style.scss and click save for the style.css to update. 

Is it supposed to automatically update? It isn't for me

Comment: Yes, when you update any partial, it should automatically recompile your `style.CSS` file. Check your VSC settings to make sure that it's watching for changes in your partials as well. There is no reason that you should have to resave `style.SCSS` everytime

Comment: so I made a change to "_header.scss" and changed the color to green. Pressed save and the compiler showed an output of 

"Change Detected...
_header.scss
--------------------
Compiling Sass/Scss Files: 
--------------------
Watching...
--------------------"

Nothing has changed on my style.css. What do I do?

Comment: Yeah, any change I make to the partial, the compiler shows a change detected and said, "Compiling Sass/Scss Files: but nothing will update until I hit save on style.scss. If anyone knows a solution to point me towards I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I had to delete both the include and exclude list in the settings. I then closed the workspace and opened the folder and now it works.